# Where to find "gartel" strip for Tallis?

Tags: product-recommendation, clothing, tallit-gadol

After many years of being folded and unfolded, my Tallis has begun fraying all along the main crease line. Unfortunately, it does not have that ornamental strip that some refer to as a "gartel," which would protect it from such damage. Is there any place that sells an "aftermarket" gartel that I could use to fix up my poor Tallis?

Comment: What do you mean by "gartel"?  I assume you don't mean the *atara*?

Comment: On one site (http://www.judaicasavings.com/page.asp?id=HelpTalis#divFeatures) it's described as follows: "A Middle-band is a thin ribbon (approx. 1" wide) running from right to left in the middle on the outside, to help the folding of the Tallis."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mendelowitz talis sales and repairs in boro park, brooklyn. ny. 4714 Fort Hamilton Parkway, Brooklyn NY 11219, Tel. 718-853-3219. I purchased my last talis there before last pesach and found him very cooperative. I am very satisfied with his service as opposed to buying in a regular seforim store or even from the major talis importers.

Answer (score 0):

[Ben's Tallit Shop](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/tallit-middleband/) sells such "gartels" for your tallis.